# headers of the matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In the following dataset, I need to add column and row so I know where for example employee '12' goes from employer 'a' to employer 'b'. This is my dataset

```
employerEmployeeEdges = [(12, 'a'), (15, 'a'), (17, 'a'), (12, 'a'), (15, 'a'), (23, 'b'), (12, 'b'), (18, 'b'), (12, 'b'), (12, 'b'), (15, 'a'), (12, 'a'), (15, 'a'), (15, 'a'), (24, 'c'), (12, 'c')]

employerEmployeeEdges=np.array(employerEmployeeEdges)
#print(employerEmployeeEdges)

unique_employee = np.unique(employerEmployeeEdges[:,1])
n_unique = len(unique_employee)
#print(unique_employee)


Q = np.zeros([n_unique,n_unique])

for n, employer_employee in enumerate(employerEmployeeEdges):
    #print(employer_employee)
    #copy the array for the original o be intact
    eee = np.copy(employerEmployeeEdges)
    #sustitue the current tuple with a empty one to avoid self comparing
    eee[n] = (None,None)
    #get the index for the current employee, the one on the y axis
    employee_index = np.where(employer_employee[1] == unique_employee)
    #get the indexes where the the employees letter match
    eq_index = np.where(eee[:,0] == employer_employee[0])[0]
    eq_employee = eee[eq_index,1]
    #add at the final array Q by index
    for emp in eq_employee:
        print(np.unique(emp))
        emp_index = np.where(unique_employee == emp)
        #print(emp)
        Q[employee_index,emp_index]+= 1
        #df = pd.DataFrame(Q, columns=emp, index=emp)

print(Q) 

[[26.  9.  3.]
 [ 9.  6.  3.]
 [ 3.  3.  0.]]
```

I want to add columns and row headers to this matrix above

Here is what I have done so far:

```
for index, row in enumerate(Q):
    if index < len(Q)-1:
        print('{}\t'.format(str(index + 1))),
    else:
        print(' \t'),
    print('|'.join('{0:.2f}'.format(x) for x in row))

1   26.00|9.00|3.00
2   9.00|6.00|3.00
    3.00|3.00|0.00
```

I cant for some reason add columns or rows to the array. What do I need to do? This array should be looking like (my desired output)

```
       a    b    c
a   26.00|9.00|3.00
b   9.00|6.00|3.00
b   3.00|3.00|0.00
```

***based on Andrew's help, here is the solution***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(Q)
df.index = unique_employee
df.columns = unique_employee
print(df)
      a    b    c
a  26.0  9.0  3.0
b   9.0  6.0  3.0
c   3.0  3.0  0.0
```

Comment: Try using Pandas, it handles the index and headers automatically for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas and specify `index` (row labels) and `columns` (column labels) to match your `unique_employee` array.

```
import pandas as pd 

print(Q) 
[[26.  9.  3.]
 [ 9.  6.  3.]
 [ 3.  3.  0.]]

df = pd.DataFrame(Q)
df.index = unique_employee
df.columns = unique_employee
print(df)
      a    b    c
a  26.0  9.0  3.0
b   9.0  6.0  3.0
c   3.0  3.0  0.0
```

Comment: yes if my matrix had that many rows*columns. Actually my matrix is pretty big and I need to match match that against it. my column headers are determined by the for loop in the code.

Comment: You'll need to do a better job explaining the logic behind your column and row labels if you want help. You have a simple problem, but have not made it clear what is going on. What do the paired values in your initial list represent? What do the values in your final matrix represent? How are those values related to the inputs? What is the purpose of labeling the first two rows in your second block of syntax? etc.

Comment: Hi Andrew, sorry. I was not clear while asking question but i thought it was going to be intuitive. If you run   print(np.unique(emp)) you will see the list of employer which is what needs to be column or row header. I am trying to construct the people's job movement. For this toy data 'a' (string) represent the employer and '12' (integer) represent the employee.

Comment: `print(np.unique(emp))` prints out individual array elements a, b, b, b, a .... and so on for at least 30 elements.

I don't understand how you are getting a, b, c for columns and a, b, b for rows. if you can help me understand that, I can help you generate labels

Comment: Right. remember those are uniques and need to got into headers. thats where I could not make this work and seeking help

Comment: remember those are unique and should be included in those three (but when I run larger go generate 'employerEmployeeEdges' those values will change. Intuitively, over the time people change jobs so do the employers add and replace employess, this is all I am looking into. The number 26 in Matrix represents the counting that how many times there has been employee exchanges between a and a.

Comment: so is a, b, b, for row labels a typo? should it read a, b, c? if so you just need to set df.index = unique_employee and same for df.columns

Comment: columns should read as [a, b, c, d, e, ......] so does rows  [a, b, c, d, e, ......]

Comment: ok, in that case I'll adjust my solution. the answer I just wrote in comments will work

Comment: great. trying here that too. thanks for help, Andrew.